# Marble: Frame changes in array

Tags: testing, jestjs, marble

Update: Is it possible to manually add a frame after the observable emits a value and ends?
The complete sign adds a frame.

I'm trying to implement a marble testing in my app and the test is:

```
const c$ = delete('1');
const expected = cold('a|', {a: {id: '1'}})
expect(c$).toBeObservable(expected);
```

Here my delete function is a mock for service's function and is basically

```
delete = service.deletePath = (id): Observable<any> => {
    return of({id});
};
```

My test fails as in my returned array, the frame changes for the second object.

Can someone please tell me why (ain't nothing but a headache))?
[See the difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baFRc.png)

Comment: It seems like the "|" (complete) adds a one time frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parentheses solved the problem.

'a|' was considered as two independent/different objects, each with its frame.
With '(a|)' objects are both in one frame now.